# Flask RESTful create_app using Celery Problem

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, celery, flask-restful

I am new to Python Flask RESTful API. Now the project that I'm working on was pre built from the previous developers. I am able to put more logic into this project. Now as requirements goes I need to use CELERY for extensive calculations. I went through different articles in the WEB (e.g. https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/celery-and-the-flask-application-factory-pattern) and other articles here but still no luck on this.

```
[repo: tracker/]
   __init.py__
   app.py
   config.py
   models.py
   celery.py
   tasks.py
   /resources/locate.py
   /resources/create.py
```

**init**.py - has the following contents:

```
from tracker import app
```

app.py - has the following contents:

```
from tracker.resources.locate import Locate
from tracker.resources.create import Create

from .celery import create_celery
from .redis_repo import redis_store
from .config import app_config
from .models import db

import collections

def create_app(config_name):

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(app_config[config_name])

    api = Api(app, catch_all_404s=True)
    api.add_resource(Locate, '/api/v1/locate/<string:ud>', methods=['GET'])
    api.add_resource(Create, '/api/v1/create/<string:ud>', methods=['GET','POST'])

    redis_store.init_app(app)
    db.init_app(app)

       return app

    app = create_app('development')

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(threaded=True, debug=False)
```

config.py - has the following contents:

```
import tempfile

class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = True
    SQLALCHEMY_POOL_SIZE = 10
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgres://xxx'
    REDIS_URL = "redis://127.0.0.1:32769/0" 
    CELERY_BROKER_URL = "redis://127.0.0.1:32769/0"
    CELERY_BACKEND = "db+postgresql://xxx" 

app_config = {'development': DevelopmentConfig}
```

models.py - has the following contents:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import func, exc, or_
import datetime
from sqlalchemy_utils import UUIDType

import tracker

db = SQLAlchemy()

class T_Logs(db.Model)
      ....
      ....
      ....
```

locate.py - has the following contents:

```
from flask import request, current_app, jsonify, after_this_request
from flask_restful import Resource
from sqlalchemy import exc

from tracker import models, config, redis_repo, utility
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

import uuid, json

class Locate(Resource):

    def get(self, ud):
    ....
    ....
```

Using those documentations or tutorials, it's quite easy to run and understand how these works. But putting it altogether in our implementations it doesnt seem to work.

with celery.py

```
from celery import Celery

def create_celery(app=None):
    application = app or create_app
    celery = Celery(app.import_name,
                    broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    TaskBase = celery.Task

    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        abstract = True

        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with application.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery
```

And sample tasks.py

```
from app import create_celery

@celery.task(name="tasks.add")
def add(a,b):
    return a+ b
```

So when I run these via visual studio code, I dont see any errors or warnings.
But when i run this on the other command prompt to start the worker:

```
celery -A app.tasks.add worker -l info -P eventlet
```

It saying
        from tracker.resources.locate import Locate
        ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tracker'

It never get executed. I'm not yet trying to call the tasks on the resources yet, But I cant proceed yet to understand how to do this.

If anyone could possibly enlighten me with this it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have manage to solve the issue, it seems that the problem is on the absolute path.

so made some relevant changes like:

```
try:
   from tracker.resources.locate import Locate
except ImportError:
   from resources.locate import Locate
```

And so with the other import statements.

Now my next problem is, How can I call the task let say inside Locate Route in GET method.

```
class Locate(Resource):

    def get(self, ud):
```

Let me know if any has an idea on this.

Comment: Just sharing... I actually solved the issue as well by calling the task inside model.py... So in locate.py, I instantiate the object from model.py and model.py call the task from there.

Comment: I think importing flask current_app would work. I have same kind of problems try to solve this noodles problem. KYU